# What information should be delivered to the client so they have enough information to manage their exchange rate risks?

Tags: risk, risk-management, fx, value-at-risk, market-risk

The client can be a CFO or CEO. The information can indicators, charts, graphs, statistics, ratios, etc.

I know the VaR is one of them.

Answer (score 2):

For business purposes, a CFO/CEO typically won't be interested at low-level modeling. Metrics such as:

- Maximum portfolio gross/net exposure (hence gross/net leverage)
- Maximum per trade size per product
- Maximum intraday exposure per product

are probably among the more important ones for business decisions.

Answer (score 2):

A CFO typically is not involved in managing risk, though that's not always the case.

If your hypothetical CFO is involved in the day-to-day managing of FX risk, the following could be useful:

- MtM
- VaR & Stressed VaR
- Expected shortfall
- Correlation between traded currency pairs
- Sensitivities (Greeks)

If your hypothetical CFO isn't involved in the day-to-day management of risk, VaR and Stressed VaR are great metrics because they sum up information into a single number.

Answer (score 0):

- Offer rates for options and currency futures.
- Upcoming publications for economic indicators for short term FX exposure.
- Future interest rate decisions for long term exposure.
- Regression for predicting trends.

An equation I made for potential risk exposure:

- x = Days of exposure.
- p = Current price.
- delta = Historical daily price changes. Subscript is how many days into the past.
- s = average of delta.

[image]